# Getting OR instead of AND in multiple word query search

Tags: solr

When I do a query on a single word my faceting

works well however when I search multiple word Solr treats each word as OR. For example linear algebra, returns linear and then algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the default settings, you can change it in `schema.xml`. Find the line that looks like this:

```
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>
```

and change the `OR` to `AND`.

If you don't want to change the global default or you don't have access to it, you can use [local params](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LocalParams) and prefix `{!q.op=AND}` to the query you send across to Solr.